# CameraManager class cannot be initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a custom camera app in android and I'm using Kotlin language.
I'm trying to access `getcameraIdList()` method of `CameraManager` but I'm unable to create an instance of `CameraManager`

Here is the code snippet

```
private fun getCameraList() {
    val cameraManager = CameraManager()
    //cameraManager.cameraIdList
}
```

I'm getting this error in Android Studio:

> Cannot access '': it is package-private in 'CameraManager'

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate this class directly, you get it from the Context.

```
val camaeraManager = context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
```